# Play Store Pre-launch: limited to devices that support ArCore even though "com.google.ar.core" is set to "optional"

Tags: android, arcore

After adding ArCore support to app, and setting `com.google.ar.core` to `optional` in manifest file (as shown below), I'm seeing that Play Store Pre-Launch tests only seem to run on devices that support ArCore. Anyone else seeing this?

```
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.ar.core" android:value="optional" />
```

Comment: I think the pre-launch testing uses "popular" devices by default, and the ar.core feature is not considered (I looked at an app without ar, and it tested with all ar-compatible devices too).  I think one way around this is to set up a custom test and select non-ar devices to run it on.

Comment: The thing is though that I've configured arcore usage as optional so it shouldn't depend on running on device that has arcore (the ar functionality gets disabled in that case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the issue turned out to be that I still had `android.hardware.camera.ar` set to required....when I updated as following then expected list of devices was now shown as supported.

```
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.ar" android:required="false"/>
```

Comment: In my case adding above does not make difference, So i added `tools:replace="android:required"` as i noticed one of my library was making it `required = true`. So i override it by adding replace tool.